# How to use php to access sqlite if the sqlite file contents is stored in shared memory?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, shared-memory

I am making a website, this website has a 100MB sqlite file, this file will not be updated.

This db file has only one table, that means every request will search in 100MB data, so I worry about the performance when many people view the website

I plan to use memory to speed up the website, but I don't have admin right of the server(including mysql), so I cannot install software such as memcached redis. I need a native/default solution.

So I choose shared memory, I write this program to cache whole sqlite file in memory.

But I don't know how to access the file in memory, because PDO only accept string DSN

How can I access database in memory?

```
$size=filesize ( "mydb.sqlite" );
$data=file_get_contents("mydb.sqlite");
$systemid = 12; // System ID for the shared memory segment
$mode = "c"; // Access mode
$permissions = 0755; // Permissions for the shared memory segment
$shmid = shmop_open($systemid, $mode, $permissions, $size);
shmop_write($shmid, $data, 0);


// used in other process
$size = shmop_size($shmid);
$sqlite_file_data=shmop_read($shmid, 0, $size);
```

If it is impossible, I will rewrite this program to use stdClass to store whole database, 
to store a php object to shared memory, I need convert it to json string, to deserialize a 100MB json in every request may cost many CPU and time. 
Can I directly store a raw object to memory?

Answer (score 0):

Your file will be already cached in memory due to trivial file cache, so don't worry.

It always make me wonder though, why people expect "many people to view the website" given said website is hosted on a shared hosting even without a database access.